# Protobuf Importing Message from another proto C# projects

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, proto

I'm using Google.Protobuf.Tools in a C# .NET Standard project `MyProject`. I have multiple proto definitions.

**MyProject/Protos/Requests/SampleRequest.proto**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "My.Projects.Protos.Requests";


package sampleRequests;

message SampleRequest {
   int32 requestNumber =1;
   SubRequest request =2;
}
```

**MyProject/Protos/Requests/SubRequest.proto**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "My.Projects.Protos.Requests";

package subRequests;

message SubRequest {
   int32 SubId =1;
   string requestText =2;
}
```

Now, this code would not compile and the error shown is SubRequest is unknown.

I would like to know how to import a different proto file so that I can achieve this. I don't really understand `--proto_path` cli options and could not find any clear documentation around this.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. What is the solution of this, Jins?

Comment: hey. I ended up using sing file. :(

Answer (score 2):

When evaluation an import, it is tested againsts each `--proto_path` to see if a suitable match can be found. For example, you could have the files side by side in the `Requests` folder, use `--proto_path` to give the location of the **Protos** folder, and talk relative to there inside the proto:

```proto
import "Requests/SubRequest.proto";
```

Note also that you need to think about packages; they aren't in the same package, so you can qualify it explicitly by starting with a `.`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
import "Requests/SubRequest.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "My.Projects.Protos.Requests";


package sampleRequests;

message SampleRequest {
   int32 requestNumber =1;
   .subRequests.SubRequest request =2;
}
```

Comment: Is the `--proto_path` thing something I need to do or is it something the compiler does?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the  above is something I need to do when handling a C# project using proto please direct me to some kind of documentation

Comment: @JinsPeter which compiler? `--proto_path` is literally an argument to the Google protobuf schema compiler, (aka "protoc") so if you mean that: yes. If you're using protobuf-net: it: the optional command line tools ("protogen") mimic "protoc". The C# compiler has no interest in .proto files whatsoever. You might be talking about the build add-in? if so, you might be looking for https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md ?